# Error while compiling php - DSO missing

Tags: php, ubuntu

I compiled php7 as below

```
./configure --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-exif --enable-dba --enable-ftp --with-gettext --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-wddx --enable-zip --with-readline --with-curl  --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --prefix=/usr

# sudo make
```

**sudo make throws following error**

/usr/bin/ld: ext/curl/.libs/interface.o: undefined reference to symbol 'CRYPTO_set_id_callback@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1

make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1

Comment: sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl?

Comment: @strangeqargo yup, already installed
apt-get install -y git-core autoconf bison libxml2-dev libbz2-dev libmcrypt-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libltdl-dev libpng-dev libpspell-dev libreadline-dev make

Comment: take a look here, for example, might be helpful https://github.com/kasparsd/php-7-debian/blob/master/build.sh, maybe you just should clone this repo

Comment: @strangeqargo got the solution by your answer. 
./configure --with-readline --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/bin --with-curl=/usr/local  --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --prefix=/usr

Comment: @strangeqargo you may repost your answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems you're missing configure flag `--with-openssl=/path/to` http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php
it's not needed for php, but it's needed for curl, I guess

**correction**

Author got it working with
`./configure --with-readline --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/bin --with-curl=/usr/local --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc`

Comment: thanks for your time, got it resolved after hours :P